# app-input only shows label after making emailForm an instance of FormGroup

Tags: angular

My input elements to sign in disappeared and it now only shows the label after I added in emailForm as an instance of FormGroup in the email form component class. I did not expect that at all:

```
<h3>Sign In</h3>
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="ui form" [formGroup]="authForm">
  <app-input
    inputType="text"
    label="Username"
    [control]="authForm.get('username')"
  >
  </app-input>

  <app-input
    inputType="password"
    label="Password"
    [control]="authForm.get('password')"
  >
  </app-input>

  <div *ngIf="authForm.errors" class="ui red basic label">
    <p *ngIf="authForm.errors.credentials">
      Invalid username or password
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button class="ui submit button primary">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I added this `controlType` property inside of the input component to decide whether to show an input or a text area:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css'],
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  @Input() inputType: string;
  @Input() controlType: 'input';

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  showErrors() {
    const { dirty, touched, errors } = this.control;
    return dirty && touched && errors;
  }
}
```

Even if undo the work done on this input component or email form component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Email } from '../email';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-email-form',
  templateUrl: './email-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./email-form.component.css'],
})
export class EmailFormComponent implements OnInit {
  emailForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() email: Email;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const { subject, from, to, text } = this.email;
    this.emailForm = new FormGroup({
      to: new FormControl(to, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      from: new FormControl({ value: from, disabled: true }),
      subject: new FormControl(subject, [Validators.required]),
      text: new FormControl(text, [Validators.required]),
    });
  }
}
```

I am unable to get back the input fields for signing in.

Comment: Can you include the actual HTML where it shows what is missing exactly?

Comment: @FabianStrathaus, the HTML at the top is where the input fields are missing.